# How to display section according to month

Tags: php

I need help I tried everything but nothing works

Below is my code where I am using permissions if the admin assigns permission to `team_lead(4)` to fill general section of **January** month of user whose `id = 2`, then it works fine but if the admin  again assigns permission to `team_lead(4)` to fill management section of **March** month of user whose `id = 2`, then in both months of `user_id`, it displays both section instead of that  it has to display general section in **January** and management section on **March**, please provide me solution for this.

Controller code

```
 $user_id= $this->data['user_id'] = $this->_user['user_id'];
       $q ="select distinct assigned_for , employee.month from section_permissions 
            join employee on (employee.user_id = section_permissions.assigned_for) 
            where section_permissions.user_id = '$user_id' and employee.emp_id =".$emp_id;
      $assigns = $this->section_permission_model->q_single($q); 

       $q = " select group_concat(distinct section_id) as allowed_sections ,section_permissions.user_id from section_permissions join employee on 
        (employee.user_id = section_permissions.assigned_for) where section_id != 0  and section_permissions.user_id = '$user_id' and section_permissions.assigned_for =".$assigns['assigned_for'];
        $row = $this->section_permission_model->q_single($q);
       $allowed = ($row['allowed_sections'])?explode(',',$row['allowed_sections']):array();

        $q = " select distinct section_id, section_permissions.user_id from section_permissions join employee on 
        (employee.user_id = section_permissions.assigned_for) where section_id != 0 and  section_permissions.user_id = '$user_id'  and section_permissions.assigned_for = ".$assigns['assigned_for'];
        $sections = $this->data['sections'] = $this->section_permission_model->q($q);
```

In view I use:

```
<?php foreach($sections as $section){ ?>
    <?php foreach($employees as $employee){?>


    <?php if($section['section_id']== 1 && in_array($section['section_id'],$allowed)){?>
<?}?>   
<?}?>   
<?}?>
```

As for every section I used `section_id == 2,3` accordingly; 
please provide me solution.

Sections

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [section_id] => 1
            [user_id] => 3
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [section_id] => 3
            [user_id] => 3
        )

)
```

Employee array

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [emp_id] => 11
            [user_id] => 5
            [month] => May
            [year] => 2016
            [punt] => 5 
            [rel] => 5
            [attend] => 5
            [comm] => 5
            [technical] => 
            [dedication] => 
            [deadline] => 
            [team] => 
            [prof] => 
            [org] => 
            [accu] => 
            [respons] => 
            [ability] => 
            [team_work] => 
            [attempt] => 
            [indep] => 
            [speed] => 
            [accur] => 
            [engage] => 

            [total] => 20
            [mgmt_total] => 
            [prof_total] => 
            [know_total] => 
            [per_total] => 
            [grand_total] => 
            [gen_cmmt] => 
            [mgmt_cmmt] => 
            [prof_cmmt] => 
            [know_cmmt] => 
            [pers_cmmt] => 

        )

)
```

Comment: could you please add your $sections and $employees array here to get a clear idea

Comment: have a look on my edited question

Comment: To debug the code you should dump the sql queries and check what is wrong with them

Comment: how it can be done

Comment: If you're extracting the data from a single SELECT and you can have different sections (management, general) as result of that SELECT you need to separate when generating the HTML, you should have a variable with the last_section you're processing. When that variable called last_section it's different than the section you're processing at that moment you should print the header section.

Comment: please tell me what changes can i made in my function